# sending a large file with SCP to a certain server stalls at exactly 2112 kB

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

There is a certain ubuntu 10.04 server where if I ssh a file onto it from any server that is outside the office where this server is (meaning any of use scp-ing onto this server through LAN from within this server always works for some reason), then scp-ing fails for any file over 2112 kB in size, and is stuck at 2112 kB.
So

```
scp -vvv /home/attila-szeremi/aszeremi.tar.gz  attila@server.hu:~/aszeremi.tar.gz
```

shows something like `1% 2112KB 909.2KB/s - stalled -` dynamically at the end, where the KB/s becomes lower and lower.

Does anyone know what may be causing this and how I can fix it?

What I have tried so far:

- Limiting the speed with scp -l 2000. It just made the file sending slower, and at 2112 kB it got stuck again.
- Enabling compresison with -C. It was still stalled at the same size.

Comment: Check that the destination has room for the whole file.

Comment: Same problem. None of the [answers](http://linuxsecure.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/scp-stalled-through-firewall-ssh-no.html) helped me. I switched to `rsync` and the problem went away. Not a solution but a decent workaround im my case.

Comment: We have also found that incorrectly configured tcp intercept on a router between the sender and receiver can also stall at 2112KB.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I seemed to have found the fix. I had to set the LAN card's mtu setting to 1492 by:

```
# ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solves the SCP stalling issue I had with copying files to a CentOS 6.4 VM.  Transfers would stall at the same 2112 KB point.

Comment: Here it is 2014, running latest Debian, fresh install and this is still a problem on my PC? Thanks for the fix. Any idea why it is not 1492 out of the box?

Answer (score 34):

The only way I managed to get rid of this problem was by [disabling TCP SACK](http://linuxsecure.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/scp-stalled-through-firewall-ssh-no.html):

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04 as well. Changing the MTU or limiting the speed had not helped. After disabling SACK, I was able to go back to an unlimited speed without any problems. This should be the answer.

Comment: i get  the error: unknown oid 'net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0' on mac

Answer (score 13):

On newer Linux systems the **ifconfig** command may have been replaced by **ip**

The command to set the mtu becomes:

```
# ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1492
```

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck with the same on a **Mac OS X** and **@dav.garcia's answer** did it for me with a small change:

```
  $ sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.sack=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same problem. None of the above suggestions worked for me, but they got me on the right path. I was behind a firewall with the MTU setting set to 1300.  Setting my LAN card's MTU to really low (576, somewhat random) caused my packets to stop being dropped.

```
$ sudo ifconfig eno1 mtu 576
```

I had to do this on each of my Linux clients. For some reason, the windows machine on the same subnet didn't have a problem.