# git push origin hangs after the total message

Tags: git, github

After executing `git push origin master` on github, the push hangs and nothing happens. I'm using `https://username@github.com`. At first I had the error first that the `http.postbuffer` is too small and i changed it to `http.postbuffer=209715200`. Now it hangs after the Total line:

```
Counting objects: 203, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (197/197), done.
Writing objects: 100% (201/201), 49.41 MiB | 11.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 201 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

EDIT: There are no proxies involved

Comment: You might try setting GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 and/or GIT_TRACE=1 to see some more verbose output. You should mention if there are any proxies involved or not as well. I'd suggest being explicit about which branches too: git push origin master, so you only push master and not every local branch.

Comment: If you haven't already you may also want to pass this question to GitHub's support folks.

Comment: also have this issue with bitbucket

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may have to wait for it to finish. There is no progress bar so it looks like it's stopped but it hasn't.

Comment: It takes > 10 mins, I don't have time for this to end

Comment: After cancelling a few times, it told me to do a "git prune" and this worked

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was a permission issue on the remote repository. Once I "chowned" the remote repo directory, the push finished.

Comment: Thanks.
It happend to me after Ubuntu upgrade (I have git user locally). After system upgrade git user was not owner of /home/git/ anymore. Had to type "sudo git chown /home/git/ -R" and it solved the problem.

Comment: Also doing chown/chmod recursively is a good idea as there is already a .git-folder inside.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem as you before.

Have a look at my resolved stackoverflow question in case it may help:
[sending a large file with SCP to a certain server stalls at exactly 2112 kB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985008/sending-a-large-file-with-scp-to-a-certain-server-stalls-at-exactly-2112-kb)