# scp stalled while copying large files

Tags: bash, shell, scp

According to the needs of the experiment, I set the [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) to `8000`. After doing this, when I use `scp` to copy large files, it stalled with `0.00%`. I tried `scp -l` or `scp -C` and turning `tcp_sack` on/off, but it still didn't work. And I can't change the MTU size for experiment result comparison. Is there any other way to help?

Answer (score 110):

An attempt at a comprehensive solution, as there could be several problems and limitations depending on your situation.

### rsync

My preferred option: using [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) *doesn't give this problem* and is a bit more versatile in my opinion, e.g. it keeps track of which files are already there, so if the connection ever does break it can pick up from where it left off - [try the `--partial` flag too](https://serverfault.com/a/407829) - [among other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244585/how-does-scp-differ-from-rsync).

Instead of

```
scp local/path/some_file usr@server.com:"/some/path/"
```

you can just do

```
rsync -avz --progress local/path/some_file usr@server.com:"/some/path/"
```

I've tested this on several occasions when `scp` would give me the same problem it gave you - and now I just use rsync by default.

### Limit speed

Not a solution for OP as the MTU is fixed in this situation (and probably not the issue here), but if the culprit is a slow/unreliable connection between the two drives, setting a speed limit reduces the delays which make the TCP connection stall - at the expense of a slower transfer of course. 
This is because scp grabs all the bandwidth it can get unless you specify the maximum data rate in kilobits, like so:

```
scp -l 8192 local/path/some_file usr@server.com:"/some/path/"
```

This [doesn't always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985008/sending-a-large-file-with-scp-to-a-certain-server-stalls-at-exactly-2112-kb) though.

### Compression option

scp's -C option can [speed up](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=798617#p798617) the transfer, reducing the probability that the transfer stalls.

### Disabling TCP SACK

As mentioned by the OP, and [here](http://linuxsecure.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/scp-stalled-through-firewall-ssh-no.html).

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0
```

([or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934469/3193542))

### LAN card MTU

Again an [MTU fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985735/3193542), not necessarily of the transfer specifically though:

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

or on [newer (Linux) systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24019637/3193542):

```
ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1492
```

### Other

If all else fails, [this](http://linuxsecure.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/scp-stalled-through-firewall-ssh-no.html) lists another handful of potential solutions not included here.

The more exotic [hpn bug](https://raim.codingfarm.de/blog/2012/05/31/the-mysterious-stalled-scp-connections/) may be at fault too.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. In fact I always use it now, also for 'local' files, e.g. if I'm writing to a mounted (networked or even USB) hard drive. Saves much of the pain of drag and drop, which in Mac OS X Finder often fails at the last possible moment.

Comment: This also fixed my issue of sudo apt-get update bombing out. Nice one.

Comment: Just make sure that you are modifying the properties of  the right interface. For me sudo ip link set dev ens3 mtu 1492, fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: I tried `rsync` instead of `scp` and it was ~15 times faster and more reliable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old, I still want to share another possible solution in addition to the nice list @BrechtDeMan already provided.

In some cases the problem might be caused by a invalid speed/duplex configuration of the used link, set by auto-negotiation. My device e.g. was  running with 100 Mbps/full-duplex by default but did not properly work with this configuration.

So you might read the current configuration and the supported modes with:

`ethtool eth0`

and give it a try with a lower setting, e.g. 100 Mbps/half-duplex in my case:

`ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex half`

Answer (score 0):

When I used git bash's scp to copy a remote 6 gigabyte file to Windows, it repeatedly stalled/hung at 99%.   But when I used Ubuntu on Window's scp, it succeeded the first time.

Answer (score -1):

Any chance you're behind a Cisco ASA firewall? If so, turn off "sequence number randomization" and that'll help a lot -- also disable TCP Offload (ethtool -K $INTERFACE tso off gso off gro off) if you're on a Cisco ASA with Broadcom NICs in your server.