# SSH debug packet types

Tags: unix, ssh

Does anyone know where I can find the descriptions of the SSH packet types received?

I am having trouble connecting via ssh to a router of mine and in the ssh debug I am receiving a packet type 1 from the router before disconnecting. Can't seem to find out what this mean.

Router IP address have been changed

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from 192.168.1.1 port 22:11:
```

Answer (score 19):

[This document](http://www.snailbook.com/docs/assigned-numbers.txt) describes the following excerp of initially used packet types from the numbering scheme in detail.

```
     Message ID                            Value    Reference
     -----------                           -----    ---------
     SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT                       1     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_IGNORE                           2     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED                    3     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_DEBUG                            4     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST                  5     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT                   6     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_KEXINIT                         20     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS                         21     [SSH-TRANS]
     SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST                50     [SSH-USERAUTH]
     SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE                51     [SSH-USERAUTH]
     SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS                52     [SSH-USERAUTH]
     SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER                 53     [SSH-USERAUTH]
     SSH_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST                  80     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_REQUEST_SUCCESS                 81     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_REQUEST_FAILURE                 82     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN                    90     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION       91     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE            92     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST           93     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA                    94     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA           95     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF                     96     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE                   97     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST                 98     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS                 99     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE                100     [SSH-CONNECT]
```

In your case you (your ssh client) sent the packet type `50` which is `SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST` as described in plain text by the debug line starting with `debug2`. Afterwards you receive a packet type `1` from the ssh server telling your client to disconnect without a specific reason (User auth failure would have been packet type `51`).

So in order to tell you what your issue is exactly with this little information is not possible, but I hope the link to the documentation helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way

[scp stalled while copying large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625000/scp-stalled-while-copying-large-files)

LAN card MTU
Again an MTU fix, not necessarily of the transfer specifically though:

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

or on newer (Linux) systems:

```
ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1492
```