# How to push or upload images to github?

Tags: git, github

I tried to use **terminal** to push a folder with images to Github but it stuck after `total` each time just as below.

```
Counting objects: 203, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (176/176), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 22.12 MiB | 15.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Then I tried to use **Github Desktop** to sync the commit to Github but it reminds me of `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/[name]/[repo]': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
 (128)`. I thought it is all because of the size of files and I try to push only one image(size 50KB) to Github. However, it still doesn't work and stuck at the same situation. So how can I upload or push a folder with images quickly to my Github remote repo???

Comment: What is the total size of the folder, and realize that this total size might be sent to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

First, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084403/6309), make sure the push is actually frozen. It might simply take longer than usual.

Second, you can indeed add, commit and push picture after picture (preferably with a script)
You also could have a [local network configuration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985735/6309) (unrelated to Git)

Third, make sure to use the latest release from Git (which GitHub Desktop does not; the latest one 82770ca uses git version 2.9.0.windows.1 from last June), which has more precise progress indicators when pushing (actually, [it will be in Git 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788417/6309), which should be released in two weeks).
And [set your buffersize accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/6309).

Finally, for really large binaries (or large number of them), you could also consider [GitHub LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The thing is when I try to push only one image it still doesn't work but when I push multi files(`.css` and `.html`) it works fine. So I think there's nothing wrong with the internet.

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit What OS are you on? What Git version are you using?

Comment: It's `OS X Yosemite` and my git version is `git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)`

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit It would be interesting to check if the issue persists with Git 2.9.3